# What should i use a MapView or a Map Intent

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I would like to create a mapview that will have text items and a direct me button under it.

So when the activity starts up, it will drop a pin on a location specificed in the previous activity. There will then be a location name and then a direct me button. when the button is clicked it will display the route from the current location.

1. how do i drop a pin on the mapview itself
2. Would you reccomend i begin a map intent to show the directions, or could i just update the map view with the directions. (how would i go about doing both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do i drop a pin on the mapview itself

Create an `ItemizedOverlay` with an `OverlayItem` and add it to your map. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk) demonstrating this.

> Would you reccomend i begin a map intent to show the directions, or could i just update the map view with the directions. (how would i go about doing both)

There is no "map intent to show the directions". In terms of how you would "just update the map view with the directions", step #1 is to figure out where you are going to get the directions, since there is no built-in Android API for that.